# "Ответа не поступало" или "ответ не поступил"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как правильно написать в официальном письме: "ответа не поступало" или "ответ не поступил"?

Comment: Я бы написал: "Ответа не поступило" или "Ответ не поступал".